# Azure Function - Getting SocketException with HttpClient

Tags: azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, socketexception

I wrote an Azure Function that works as a micro gateway for two of my API systems. This gateway authenticates the traffic with an Auth server, calls one of the API backends, and finally report the outcome to Auth Server.

I tried to load test this Function App locally using JMeter - ran a load of 100 concurrent users hitting various URLs of both backend APIs. All look good. When I ran netstat during the load test on my local machine, func.exe shows "couple" ESTABLISHED connections to each of the backends, and a bunch for 127.0.0.1:7071 (my function runs on port 7071 locally)

When I deploy the app to Azure and run the same load, it runs fine for few seconds and then start throwing a lot of SocketException's for few seconds. This repeats.

Here's my pseudo code. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
public static class MicroGateway
{
   private static HttpClient _httpClientAuthServer;
   private static HttpClient _httpClientApi1;
   private static HttpClient _httpClientApi2;

   // static ctor to initialize and hold on to HttpClient objects for reusing
   static MicroGateway()
   {
      string backendUrlAuthServer = "https://authserver.com";
      string backendUrlApi1 = "https://www.api1.com";
      string backendUrlApi2 = "https://www.api2.com";

      ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(backendUrlAuthServer)).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;
      ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(backendUrlApi1)).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;
      ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(backendUrlApi2)).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

      _httpClientAuthServer = new HttpClient();
      _httpClientAuthServer.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendUrl);
      _httpClientAuthServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

      _httpClientApi1 = new HttpClient();
      _httpClientApi1.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendUrl);
      _httpClientApi1.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

      _httpClientApi2 = new HttpClient();
      _httpClientApi2.BaseAddress = new Uri(backendUrl);
      _httpClientApi2.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
   }

   [FunctionName("AuthRouteReport")]
   public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req,
      ILogger log,
      ExecutionContext context)
   {
      // authorize the request
      _httpClientAuthServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("apikey");
      _httpClientAuthServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apikey", _userInputKey);
      HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClientAuthServer.GetAsync("/?" + backendQueryString);

      // route the request to backend-1 or backend-2
      if (routeToB2)
      {
         _httpClientApi1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Accept");
         _httpClientApi1.DefaultRequestHea
ders.Add("Accept", req.Headers["Accept"].ToString());
         HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClientApi1.GetAsync("/?" + backendQueryString);

         // Asynchronously report response.StatusCode to _httpClientAuthServer

         return response;
      }
      else
      {
         _httpClientApi2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Accept");
         _httpClientApi2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", req.Headers["Accept"].ToString());
         HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClientApi2.GetAsync("/?" + backendQueryString);

         // Asynchronously report response.StatusCode to _httpClientAuthServer

         return response;
      }
   }
}
```

Exception Details:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<CreateConnectionAsync>d__44.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync>d__49.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__39.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext:
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

I occassionally get the same exception with a different message:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

The operation was canceled. Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or 
an application request.
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__40.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__39.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__62.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at ThreeScaleGateway.AuthRep3Scale+<Run>d__17.MoveNext (ThreeScaleGateway, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullThreeScaleGateway, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /home/vsts/work/1/s/ThreeScaleGateway/Functions/AuthRep3Scale.csThreeScaleGateway, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 157)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 63)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeAsync>d__25.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 556)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 503)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 439)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 249)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 293)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 89)

Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal+<<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|38_0>d`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__34`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<FillAsync>d__91.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync>d__89.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException:
```

Comment: It looks like you are reached connection limit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#connections-limit

Can you please share you function name privately: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: Can you share the exception details.
Also, you should ensure that you are using a single HttpClient instance across multiple invocations of your function and not create a new instance for each http call you make

Comment: Hi @AlexeyRodionov, here are the function details - it's our Dev instance: 2018-12-04T22:18:21.001     Id=47b91400-bd10-423c-a4e0-29778521eddb

Comment: Hi @alwayslearning, as I showed in my code above, I am maintaining 3 instances for 3 HTTP destinations. I followed [this suggestion](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/).    BTW, the exception is: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Comment: @AlexeyRodionov, my function is developed using VS. So, I wonder you may not see the code. Let me know so I can find an alternative.

Comment: @CodeStone, what is function app region ?

Comment: It’s in West US 2

Comment: Did you check this post? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693353/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respon

Sidenote: Guess the missing 'await' in your pseudo code is a typo,or? - 

    `HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClientAuthServer.GetAsync("/?" + backendQueryString)`

Comment: @alwayslearning, it's a typo. I have in my code and I've updated my question above. Also, not all my requests are failing. They start to fail after a minute or so into my load test. So, I am thinking it's the connection limit issue.

Comment: @AlexeyRodionov: FYI - When I ran netstat during load test on my local machine, func.exe shows "couple" ESTABLISHED connections to each of the backends, and a bunch for 127.0.0.1:7071 (my function runs at port 7071 locally)

Comment: @CodeStone did you ever figure this out?  I have the same issue on premium plan with under 100 outbound connections (10 or less for actual application outbound connections) and vnat for all outgoing traffic so nothing in the Azure environment should be a limiting factor.  Microsoft support had no ideas after they determined it wasn’t a SNAT exhaustion issue.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft docs:
"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

You should create a single static instance of HttpClient and reuse it in all your application. Consider creating a HttpClientFactory class and inject it wherethever you need to access that single instance. Don't use "using" statement because HttpClient is responsible for that. Hope it helps!

Comment: This one did it for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You had exceeded outbound connections limit (300 connections) two times:
11/26 23:50 GMT
11/27 02:35 GMT
That's why you got a lot of `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` exceptions around these times.

Then you tested with additional instance around 11/27 21:00 GMT and you didn't reach connection limit. So you should scale out your app(App Service plan) or try to use consumption plan.

More information about limit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#connections-limit

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. In Staging we have 3 instances, and received 30 socket exceptions this morning for few simple Pingdom checks. Below are the details of the first and last occurrences. Can you please check these as well?

12/5/2018 3:45:31 PM  UTC // First exception
7252dbbf-74dc-40a8-895f-935729b550e8 
...
12/5/2018 4:02:29 PP UTC  // Last exception
2350e3d2-5956-4857-b4d8-589387558f08 

If I am reusing a fixed number (4) of HttpClient objects, I wonder why those many connections are being opened instead of reusing. Is there anything that I need to change in my code?