# Unable to interact with an API in web app but it works in console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I'm migrating my existing console app to a web app. I'm making an api call in the controller. The below code works perfectly in console app. But in web app,i get exception at
`var result = webClient.DownloadString(sourceUrl);`
with the message `"unable to connect to remote server"` and the inner exception says `{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond}System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}`

I have tried to pass the url as uri object, edited web.config file to include default credentials, servicepointmanager etc. I have also tried to make it asynchronous using async and await. I really do not know what is going on. I'm behind a corporate proxy but the api call works perfectly in console app and Postman.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace webApp.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        private string sourceUrl="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us&appid=YOURID";
        [Route("")]
        public void GetAlldata()
        {
            var dataCall = DownloadData(sourceUrl);

        }


        private string DownloadData(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                IWebProxy wp = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
                wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                webClient.Proxy = wp;
                var result = webClient.DownloadString(sourceUrl);

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd troubleshoot the connectivity layer of the client to the API.

Comment: Hi cmoe. Have you tried Googling the error message? I found this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693353/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respon

Comment: Hi Chris, I've seen that link. That is what my last paragraph highlights.

Comment: `the api call works perfectly in console app and Postman.` Fiddler is a good tool for seeing the differences between different calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mention that after trying the above code in my home network and it worked, I pinpointed the problem to be a proxy issue. Removing the below from my code

```
 IWebProxy wp = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
    wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    webClient.Proxy = wp;
```

and explicitly adding the below to web.config fixed it. I don't know why web app doesn't pickup the default proxy from code but console app does. Any explanation for this behavior will be appreciated.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="http://proxy.MYCOMPANY.com:8080" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Íf above solution(cmoe's answer) don't work for your case. May be The console app pass proxy but other app drop by firewall. Check firewall settings.