# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, .net, rest, server, ssl-certificate

I have a functionality to call rest services from my web application. I am doing this in c#.net code

My Code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
 MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc:defg!");

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CSRF_NONCE", a.NonceValue);

   var message = await client.PostAsync("hostname/Windchill/servlet/odata/v3/ProdMgmt/Parts('OR:wt.part.WTPart:123456')/PTC.ProdMgmt.GetPartStructure?$expand=Components($select=PartName,PartNumber;$expand=PartUse($select=FindNumber,LineNumber,Quantity,Unit);$levels=1)", null);
  }
```

1. I can call it successfully from my local machine but when I try to call it after deploying to the Test server (Windows Server), I get the below error.

   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

I tried doing the below to make it functional but nothing has worked.

1. ["A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time" using WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693353/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respon)
2. Added the below code in the constructor method

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

3. My Test server uses proxy settings in the browser to access the rest services url. So I tried adding Proxy details in my code.

> WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy
> {
> Address = new Uri($"http://x.x.x.x:xxxx"),
> };
> ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
> HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
> {
> AllowAutoRedirect = true,
> AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
> Proxy = proxy,
> };
> using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to look at the "10060" part, which is socket error code [WSAETIMEDOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2#WSAETIMEDOUT).

This indicates a TCP socket is unable to connect because the remote party didn't respond.

Check that the hostname/port is correct, server is online, firewall isn't dropping packets etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response Cory. When you say hostname/port, is it the rest services hostname? If so, I am able to successfully access the same from my local machine browser

Comment: The URL you pass in. You have a connectivity issue; it's time to troubleshoot.