# Fail to call API from aother server ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, api, iis

I have an API call in ASP.NET Core project, everything works fine in localhost, but not in IIS. The error I get is **"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."**

Following is the StackTrace:

System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at AILS.Mobile.Base.Controllers.UtilController.GetPostRequest[T](String url, Object requestData, Boolean getReq)

Here is my code to call API:

```
        BaseResponse<T> responseResult = new BaseResponse<T>();
        Type _obj = typeof(T);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(!url.Contains("handshake") ? GetCookie(ASMobileConstant.CookiesKey.BaseURL) + url : url);
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                string content = string.Empty;

                if (getReq)
                {
                    response = await client.GetAsync(builder.Uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    response.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestData), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    response = await client.PostAsync(builder.Uri, httpContent);
                    content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    response.Dispose();
                }

                if (_obj != typeof(clsResponse))
                {
                    responseResult = new BaseResponse<T>(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<clsResponse>(content));
                }
                else
                {
                    responseResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseResponse<T>>(content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responseResult.IsGood = false;
                responseResult.Message = ex.Message;
                myLogger.Error("catch {0}", ex.Message);
                myLogger.Error("catch {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Let's say my domain name is xxx.ask.com, the url will be http://xxx.ask.com/mobileapi/Login

I have used POSTMAN to test manually and it works perfectly.

I have no idea on which setting can be set, please help.

Question: Can HTTPS website call HTTP API?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693353/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respon Try this link might help

Comment: Does http://xxx.ask.com automatically redirect to https?

Comment: @DSander no, it won't

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Can HTTPS website call HTTP API?

Browser security restricts a webpage from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the webpage. This restriction is called the same-origin policy. The same-origin policy restricts (but doesn't prevent) a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. To make requests from the browser to an endpoint with a different origin, the endpoint must enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

For more information, see [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0).