VB.NET getRequestStream function not working in IIS
api.Method = "POST"
api.ContentType = "application/json"
api.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate) 'correct certificate added here
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Nothing
api.ContentLength = 0
Try
    If objectInput IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim data As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectInput) 'objectInput has valid requestbody
        byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
        api.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Using dataStream As IO.Stream = api.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        End Using
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    textToAppend = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " error in streamdata write " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(api)
    File.AppendAllText(filePathLogs, textToAppend & Environment.NewLine)
    textToAppend = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " error in streamdata write " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex)
    File.AppendAllText(filePathLogs, textToAppend & Environment.NewLine)
End Try

Where logged data:
api body:
{
    "_HttpRequestHeaders":["Content-Type","Host"],
    "_Proxy":
    {
        "Credentials":null
    },
    "_KeepAlive":true,
    "_Pipelined":false,
    "_AllowAutoRedirect":true,
    "_AllowWriteStreamBuffering":true,
    "_HttpWriteMode":1,
    "_MaximumAllowedRedirections":50,
    "_AutoRedirects":0,
    "_Timeout":100000,
    "_ReadWriteTimeout":300000,
    "_MaximumResponseHeadersLength":64,
    "_ContentLength":643,
    "_MediaType":null,
    "_OriginVerb":{},
    "_ConnectionGroupName":null,
    "_Version":
    {
        "Major":1,
        "Minor":1,
        "Build":-1,
        "Revision":-1,
        "MajorRevision":-1,
        "MinorRevision":-1
    },
    "_OriginUri":"https://svcproxy-csc-itg.it.hpe.com/gw/hpit/sapgts/gtslicense/1.0"
}

and
ex body:
{
    "ClassName":"System.Net.WebException",
    "Message":"Unable to connect to the remote server",
    "Data":null,
    "InnerException":
    {
        "NativeErrorCode":10060,
        "ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
        "Message":"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond",
        "Data":null,
        "InnerException":null,
        "HelpURL":null,
        "StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)",
        "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
        "RemoteStackIndex":0,
        "ExceptionMethod":"8\nDoConnect\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Sockets.Socket\nVoid DoConnect(System.Net.EndPoint, System.Net.SocketAddress)",
        "HResult":-2147467259,
        "Source":"System",
        "WatsonBuckets":null
    },
    "HelpURL":null,
    "StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()\r\n   at TechPro.download_content.API_CALL(HttpWebRequest api, String method, String ContentType, Object objectInput, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate, String referenceNumber, Boolean isStatusCheck) in C:\\Users\\sumitm\\Documents\\TechPro\\Source Code\\techpro\\TechPro\\download_content.aspx.vb:line 390",
    "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
    "RemoteStackIndex":0,
    "ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetRequestStream\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.HttpWebRequest\nSystem.IO.Stream GetRequestStream(System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)",
    "HResult":-2146233079,
    "Source":"System",
    "WatsonBuckets":null
}


My system is a windows virtual machine within my organization VPN.
When I run this same code using Visual Studio Community IIS Express on same machine, It works fine.
When I hit same request using Postman on same machine, it works fine.
But when I host this application on IIS, it fails with above log data I have posted.
I have website binding 443 added with the certificate.
I am clueless what is going wrong.

Also when I create console application using the same code, and run in the same server, it also works fine and gives response.

Got it resolved by following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693353/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respon
